# Trying to use the mail function in PHP on a local host

Tags: php, localhost, sendmail

I'm trying to use the mail function on a php website that I'm hosting on a local server (using USBWebServer v8.6) and I keep getting this error.

*Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing in E:\USBWebserver v8.6\root\insert.php on line 29*

The code I'm using is getting data from a form have I missed something?

```
<?php
echo "Company Name: ".$_POST['companyname']."<br>";
echo "Address:  ".$_POST['address']."<br>";
echo "Phone Number: ".$_POST['phonenumber']."<br>";
echo "Email:    ".$_POST['email']."<br>";

mail($_POST['email'], "You have Registered", "You have Registered");
?>
```

The suggestion I keep getting is to do something to php.ini, but I'm confused as to what exactly I'd need to do

Comment: You must have a from header in the `mail()` function, This can be set with the additional_headers parameter, or a default can be set in php.ini

Comment: Read the manual? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 1):

You have to fill out all parameters (unless you edit the PHP.ini file) to include all of the data, the `mail()` function accepts parameters like so:

```
mail($to, $subject, $body, $from);
```

however in order for the mail to actually be sent you also need to make sure your server is running a mail server.

Comment: `mail($to, $subject, $message)` will do fine. The last part is what's important here: you need to be running a mail server to be able to send mails off the system.

Comment: @AmalMurali are you sure the from parameter can be null? the docs say that it's required: `When sending mail, the mail must contain a From header. This can be set with the additional_headers parameter, or a default can be set in php.ini.
Failing to do this will result in an error message similar to Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing. The From header sets also Return-Path under Windows.` though not necesarily in the parameter. It can be set in the `ini` file.